# CellForRowAtIndexPath called before ViewWillAppear finished running

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have an application that pulls information from a Parse database, and displays it in a UITableView. I pull the information from parse in the viewWillAppear function, and i display it in the tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath) function. Sometimes i receive an error because the array that stores the Parse information has a length of 0, and i try to access information at an index outside of the bounds of the array. I believe this is because the cellForRowAtIndexPath is getting called before the viewWillAppear is finished running. Is this possible or is my error definitely coming from somewhere else?

EDIT: The error does not occur every time, and i cannot find a way to reproduce it

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //begin ignoring events until the information is finished being pulled
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    resultsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    //run query
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Answers")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

                    //append information to the resultsArray 
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    //information is now pulled, so allow interaction 
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! answerCell

    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    resultsArray[indexPath.row].imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        //set image within cell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: put some code from your side

Comment: please see code @Graham

Comment: please put a break point in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then run and see step by step what is going on. then the same time you  can see your arry is null or not.

Comment: Can you show the code for `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection returns resultsArray.count @Paulw11

Comment: Just checking, since I'm not familiar with Parse SDK: is it certain that the query callbak is called on the main thread? It's not specified on their documentation and would cause issues on the reload to be called in a bg thread.

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition. Change your code so that your data from parse is loaded into a temporary array and then assign this array to the property array when you are done. This means you won't need the `removeAll` which is probably contributing to your issue

Comment: At which point should i assign the temp array to the correct array to make sure this works? @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you load your data from Parse into a temporary array and then assign this to your property array right before you call `reloadData` - this will avoid any potential race conditions and remove the need for the `removeAll` which is potentially a big part of your problem;

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //begin ignoring events until the information is finished being pulled
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()



    //run query
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Answers")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        var localArray=[SomeType]()

        if let objects = objects {

                    //append information to the localArray 
                }
            }
            self.resultsArray=localArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    //information is now pulled, so allow interaction 
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

}
```

Comment: It is strange that this fixed the problem. I wonder why it happened... But thank you anyway!

Comment: arrays aren't thread safe, so any time you update from one thread and read from another you can have problems

Comment: @rohaldb, if you look at my answer you will find "what actually happened" (further to the comment of @Paulw11).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in `viewWillAppear` you have a background block `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` that has some work to do in a different thread (AKA off the main thread), that means that viewWillAppear will finish while the block will get a callback.

This explains why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called after `viewWillAppear` finishes, because of the callback block.

That means that everything is alright and `viewWillAppear` actually do finish a legit "run".

You can actually put a breaking point inside the callback method (in `viewWillAppear`) and a breaking point inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and see when the callback happens while `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called.

If you need a different method from Parse perhaps you should look in their [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually if your callback not access to `self.tableView`, everything will go on as you think as usual. You can have a try.

It happened to me when I access to the view on the screen in `init` method `viewDidLoad` method called before `init` ends.

Anyway, you should know that fact. And you access to your `tableView` in callback (called before `viewWillAppear` finishing) which needs `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean/how to fix it.  What does "Actually if your callback not access to self.tableView" mean?

Comment: you can comment `self.tableView.reloadData()` then see what will happen.

Comment: but then the information wont be displayed in the table?

Comment: you can use log to figure out their relations.